# Unity - Dialog Box disappears without me pressing Space key

Tags: unity-game-engine, dialog

I am just following a tutorial series on Youtube which is from way back in 2020 and everything seems to work fine except for dialog box assigned ti a signboard gameobject closing on its own which is supposed to activate and close upon pressing Space Key.

I have 2 box colliders (2D) on it one for collision and one for trigger and it works fine for activating dialog box but closes immediately after.

**My Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SignDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialogBox;
    public Text dialogText;
    public string dialog;
    public bool playerInRange;

    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && playerInRange)
        {
            if(dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                dialog.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(true);
                dialogText.text = dialog;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = false;
            dialogBox.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on only seeing this code...
Do some `Debug.Log()` on every place you are doing SetActive(false) to see which part of the code is causing it (is it in the Update or is it in the OnTriggerExit2D?).

If it's the Update, you have some hardware problems with your Space key clicking multiple times. If it's the OnTriggerExit, you need to investigate why your collider is triggering the exit unexpectedly.

The code doesn't look like it has some obvious errors in it, so it's either some weird interaction in your game out of this question's context, or something completely different causing it.

Maybe you have this script added to 2 different objects? So when you click space it runs twice, one putting it to true, the other to false? Etc etc

Comment: On further debugging, my "playerInRange" seems to get disabled as soon as I press Space key even while the player is not moving out of the range area. And the dialog box gets disabled as a result of this.

Comment: The issue seems to be with "OnTriggerExit2D", if I disable it works fine but with the player boolean staying as true and activating dialog on every Space Key. I have tried enlarging and shortening the box colliders but the problem persists.